# Cant update and select in single query in mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
UPDATE sub_categories 
   set creatives_count = 
            ( SELECT COUNT(services.sub_category_id) 
                from sub_categories 
                left 
                join services 
                  on (sub_categories.id = services.sub_category_id) 
               GROUP 
                  BY sub_categories.id);
```

> BlockquoteError: Table 'sub_categories' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data.

How can I update my column with the result I obtained in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
UPDATE  sub_categories s 
join
(
  SELECT COUNT(services.sub_category_id) as cnt from sub_categories 
  left join services on sub_categories.id = services.sub_category_id
  GROUP BY sub_categories.id
)A on s.id=A.id
set creatives_count = a.cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use  inner join on the subquery

```
UPDATE sub_categories 
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT sub_categories.id my_id, COUNT(services.sub_category_id)  my_count
     FROM sub_categories 
     LEFT JOIN services ON sub_categories.id = services.sub_category_id
     GROUP BY sub_categories.id) t ON t.my_id =  sub_categories.id 
SET creatives_count =  t.my_count
```